# Как указать SQL-команду, которая должна выполнится сразу после соединения CMS с MySql (ModX revolution)?

Tags: modx, revo

Потребовалось увеличить время ожидания cоединений с базой MySql для *любых запросов* для CMS ModX Revolution.

Есть ли способ указать это, в рамках предусмотренных для этого настроек?

Нужно, чтобы сразу после успешного соединения CMS с базой, выполнилась SQL-команда `set session wait_timeout=X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не точный ответ, а скорее как направление, куда двигаться. Встроенных настроек таких нет, но есть плагины. Думаю вам подойдет плагин на событие `OnMODXInit`

Он срабатывает в конце инициализации MODX после загрузки всех необходимых сервисов (modError, modLexicon, modRegistry, cacheManager), загрузки пакетов из ExtensionPackages и инициализации сессии, в которой определяется пользователь. В плагине, срабатывающем на это событие, можно, например, загружать модели своих компонентов (если они не загружаются через ExtensionPackages). Запускается это событие в классе modX.

```
switch ($modx->event->name) {
    case 'OnMODXInit':
        // Выполняем SQL запрос
        $sql ='Ваш запрос в базу';
        $q = $modx->prepare($sql);
        $q->execute();
    break;
}
```

**Будьте осторожны**, это событие срабатывает всегда!!! и легко поймать 500 ошибку и в фронтэнде и в бэкэнде.

Если вы все же нарвались на 500 ошибку, удалите плагин с помощью phpMyAdmin в таблице prefix_site_plugins, и удалите папку с кешем /core/cache

Из минусов вижу, что это событие срабатывает после инициализации `modx`, т.е. уже будут выполнены некоторые запросы к базе, и ваша команда не будет первой, но будет раньше, чем парсинг шаблонов, чанков, сниппетов и пр.

Описание событий плагинов взял отсюда: https://modzone.ru/blog/2015/12/27/frontend-events-for-modx/

Comment: Смотрел тоже в сторону использования плагина, но думал, что может все-таки я что-то пропустил, просматривая реализацию классов  modX и xPDO... Реализовал в итоге так, как вы описали. Спасибо.